# iframe, открывающийся у посетителей с определенным referer

Tags: php, iframe

Ищу способ показа iframe пользователям с определенными referer (конкретно пришедшими с поисковых систем).
Например если пользователь заходит на сайт напрямую - iframe не показывается. Если он пришел с поисковой системы - должен показываться на странице iframe.

Comment: Ищите в переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` подстроку с именем нужного сайта. Если нашли, выводите фрейм при формировании страницы.

Comment: Не выйдет, гугл и яндекс не возращают реффер из поиска...